# HTML Email fonts automatically scaling in Opera Mail?

Tags: css, opera, html-email

I've got an HTML email with fonts sized using pixels (16px) in inlined CSS. Things work as expected in most clients, but in Opera's Mail panel (v12.01), as I shrink the width of the viewport, the font size scales down as well.

This happens in all the other HTML emails I've tested as well.

Has anyone else ever encountered this, and does anyone have a workaround?

**UPDATE 2012-08-29:**

I found an option under the spanner menu that appears in the top-right corner of email messages called "Fit to width". Unchecking this option results in Opera Mail behaving more like a standard email client.

So the question about a workaround remains... can this behavior be over-ridden by a line of code in emails, when the email creator knows that the email automatically adapts to the viewport width? I'm looking for something similar to the solution available for websites: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

You should use the values of the font-sizes inside the inner most elements that need that font sizes. for example giving a `font-size:15px;` to table wont work, rather you should give `font-size:15px;` to individual `td` elements of this table.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't solve it. I tried 3 test cases: 1) "font-size: 1em" on the containing div element, 2) "font-size: 1em" on the p tags, and 3) "font-size: 16px" on the p tags. None of the variants had any affect on Opera Mail's scaling of font sizes with window widths.

Comment: If you could share a code you have written, I will try to look into and help and possibly help you out.

Comment: All the above were inlined styles, BTW.

Comment: Here's my test email - doesn't get much simpler than this:

Comment: `<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">p.one{font-size:25px;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="one">style tag 25 px</p>
        <p style="font-size: 25px;">inline 25 px</p>
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: @Sandwich: that doesn't make much sense. But I can sense the problem.You should use inline css and not style tag.

Comment: There's inline CSS in the second p tag, which still gets resized by Opera Mail.

Comment: It wont work as this. You need to share the actual code. But I can tell you that probably you should break this p tag into a td of table and have a table structure

Comment: Converting it to table-based layout has no change on the behavior. However, I found the source of the behavior. I'll update the original question with my findings.